# Query on Eloquent based on relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have 2 models, `Transaction`, `TrackingNumber`.

The relationships and fields are:

```
Transaction: hasMany TrackingNumber

Transaction fields: id | carrier
TrackingNumber fields: id | transaction_id
```

I am trying to query TrackingNumbers but I want to return only where the carrier is ups. In this sense:

---

a) If I use eager loading, it will return all the tracking numbers regardless of shipper and only return transaction relationship based on the where:

```
$collection = TrackingNumber::with(['transaction' => function($q) {
    $q->where('carrier', 'ups')
}])->get();
```

So this is not what I want. What I want is that the `$collection` has only the TrackingNumbers with given carrier instead.

---

b) If I do something like this, the result is what I want, but it is very inefficient *(as it makes 2 queries and stores data in array; also if the array is too big, it fails on whereIn.)*

```
$transactionIds = Transaction::where('carrier', 'ups')->pluck('id');
$trackingNumbers = TrackingNumber::whereIn('id', $transactionIds)->get();

// The result is what I want but it is inefficient.
```

---

c) I also tried something like this but it doesn't care about the where :/

```
\DB::table('tracking_numbers')
   ->join('transactions', 'tracking_numbers.transaction_id', '=', 'transactions.id')
   ->where('transactions.carrier', 'ups')
   ->get();
```

---

d) I don't want to use `whereHas()` because it gets extremely slow with a lot of data (I have +1m rows in my tables)

---

What is the Laravel way to achieve this?

Comment: for the c), you should use it as `->join('transactions', function($join){
$join->on('tracking_numbers.transaction_id', '=', 'transactions.id')->where('transactions.carrier', 'ups');
})`

Comment: also, see about the joins and utilizing it as eloquent relationship https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15169 and https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/329

Answer (score 1):

Using [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) should get you the results you want:

```
TrackingNumber::whereHas('transaction', function ($query) {
    $query->where('carrier', 'ups');
})->get();
```

Or, try restructuring the query from `c` like:

```
\DB::table('tracking_numbers')
   ->join('transactions', function ($join) {
        $join->on('tracking_numbers.transaction_id', '=', 'transactions.id')
             ->where('transactions.carrier', 'ups');
   })
   ->get();
```

Comment: whereHas is the slowest way of achieving this - with big data it is extremely slow (my tables has +1m rows)